# Check if two properties and their respective values are duplicated in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an below array and wanted to return just `true` or `false` if we have two property with same value in array of object. As you can see id with `123` have same value as "one". If both are match then return `true`.

```
const data = [
  {id: 123, value: "One"},
  {id: 123, value: "One"},
  {id: 143, value: "Two"},
  {id: 153, value: "Three"}
]
```

Comment: Consider checking "accepted" the answer that was the most helpful. It increases both: your reputation record and credibility in the eyes of those whose support you might seek later on.

Answer (score 2):

You may check whether the size of unique [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of hashes (keys and values concatenated) of all objects within array is less than source array length (which may happen only if there're non-unique key/value combinations):

```js
const dup = [{id: 123, value: "One"},{id: 123, value: "One"},{id: 143, value: "Two"}, {id: 153, value: "Three"}],
      noDup = [{id: 1234, value: "One"},{id: 123, value: "One"},{id: 143, value: "Two"}, {id: 153, value: "Three"}],

      hasDup = arr => 
        new Set(arr.map(({id,value}) => `id|${id}|value|${value}`)).size < arr.length
      
console.log(hasDup(dup))   //true
console.log(hasDup(noDup)) //false
```

Or, if you need to check for duplicates across ***all*** key/value combinations:

```
const hasDup = arr => 
        new Set(arr.map(o => Object.entries(o).flat().join('|'))).size < arr.length
```

Comment: Yup with `Set` and checking the `length`, this is certainly a smart and neat way to do

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be this:

```js
const data = [{id: 123, value: "One"},{id: 123, value: "One"},{id: 143, value: "Two"}, {id: 153, value: "Three"}]

for(let i=0; i< data.length; i++){
 for(let j=i+1; j<data.length; j++){
   if(JSON.stringify(data[i]) === JSON.stringify(data[j])){
     console.log(true);
     break;
   }
 }
}
```

A better approach with O(N) complexity would be this:

```js
const data = [{id: 123, value: "One"},{id: 123, value: "One"},{id: 143, value: "Two"}, {id: 153, value: "Three"}]

var stringifyElements = data.map(i=> JSON.stringify(i));
console.log(stringifyElements)

var hashMap = {};

for(var i =0; i<stringifyElements.length; i++){
  if(hashMap[stringifyElements[i]] === 1){
    console.log(true);
    break;
  }else{
    hashMap[stringifyElements[i]] = 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code implements O(n²)-time complexity algorithm (due to nested `for(..`-loops) which is [way too expensive](https://jsbench.me/28kbj7gcd7/1) for a task like that. You could've made it a bit faster avoiding `JSON.stringify()`,  e.g. `data[i].id == data[j].id && data[i].value == data[j].value`

Comment: yeah you're right about the complexity part. However, `data[i].id == data[j].id && data[i].value == data[j].value ` would still require two loops, so same complexity. A better way to solve this would be creating `hashtable` through `for..loop` and putting the values inside that. Then again through another `for..loop` iterating through the array and matching with the hashtable. That will be O(N). I thought about that but I got lazy :D

Comment: *'...would be creating hashtable...'* That was [exactly my idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62415613/11299053), because I got even more lazy to do nested loops ;)

Comment: Haha and now your comment motivated me to actually do that. See the updated one.

Comment: I still don't like the idea of using `JSON.stringify()`, however, now it works much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if it needs an explanation.

```js
function doJob(data){
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
       let count = data.filter(item => (item.id === data[i].id && item.value === data[i].value)).length;
       if(count > 1) return true
    }
    return false;
}

const data = [
  {id: 123, value: "One"},
  {id: 123, value: "One"},
  {id: 143, value: "Two"},
  {id: 153, value: "Three"}
]

console.log(doJob(data))
```

Comment: Just fixed a few seconds after/before your comment. :)

Comment: Your code implements O(n²)-time complexity algorithm (`.filter()` nested within `for(..`-loop) which is [way too expensive](https://jsbench.me/28kbj7gcd7/1) for a task like that. You could've made it a bit faster by using *short-circuited* methods, exiting upon the first match (e.g. `Array.prototype.some()` or `Array.prototype.find()`)